# Missing some rows in the code even if the data exists in the database

Tags: sql-server

Can someone please advise on what I can do to correct this?

If I run this code without the `DT.DOC_TYPE_DESC`, I get 198 rows and if I add the `DT.DOC_TYPE_DESC`, I get 176 rows.

Which I don't understand why it might be happening as the table `CS_DOCTYPE` does have the desc in there, either way I want to see all the records even if it has the `DT.DOC_TYPE_DESC` or not.

Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    A_DOC_TYPE, COUNT(*) AS Count, DT.DOC_TYPE_DESC
FROM 
    dbo.CS_AU AU
INNER JOIN 
    vf.vis.dbo.CS_DOCTYPE DT ON DT.DOC_TYPE = AU.A_DOC_TYPE
WHERE 
    A_ACTION = 'I' 
    AND (A_DATE BETWEEN '2022-01-01'AND '2022-12-31') 
    AND A_TO_NODE = 2
    --AND A_DOC_TYPE IN ('')
GROUP BY 
    A_DOC_TYPE, DT.DOC_TYPE_DESC
ORDER BY 
    A_DOC_TYPE
```

Comment: You're adding the column to the `GROUP BY`; that *will* change the number of rows you receive as you are putting your data into different *distinct groups*. I don't see what the problem is here, as the behaviour is expected.

Comment: it shouldn't lead to less rows though?

Comment: but maybe the question is not correctly asked

Comment: It's forcing me to add it to the GROUP BY, what can I do for it to not remove those rows? I need the doc_type_desc in there too.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Adding the LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN resolved the issue. Thank you!